# passing value to progress bar in React and Reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I've never used a progress bar, so I am trying to figure out by piecing together various sources and trying to get it to work with React and Reactstrap. This is what seemed to make sense to me, but it isn't working.

This is the documentation for reactstrap regarding  `<Progress />`. Basically, it takes a `value` prop so I am trying to pass it to a method so it can be dynamically updated which in theory should make the progress bar move.

https://reactstrap.github.io/components/progress/

However, in my case the bar only updates to like 5%, but the `console.log` does update to 100.

Here is my component. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Progress
} from 'reactstrap';

export default class SectionLoading extends Component {
    progressValue() {
        let width = 1;
        return setInterval(() => {
            if (width <= 100) {
                console.log(width);
                width++;
            }
        }, 10)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Progress value={this.progressValue()} />
        ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not returning width. It would be better to use a state variable anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Progress value should take a number instead of a function. So, could you please try to change `<Progress value={this.progressValue()} />` to `<Progress value={this.state.width} />`  and then in your progressValue function use `this.setState({ width })` to update state.

Comment: How do we call the progressValue function then?

Comment: @MonicaAcha It will be based on your use case. When do you want to the progress bar start? Maybe at the beginning (call it in the componentDidMount)? Maybe after a button is clicked (call it in the button click event)?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.state = {
    loaded:0,
}
```

and

```
<React.Fragment>
  <Progress max="100" color="success" value={this.state.loaded} > 
   {Math.round(this.state.loaded,2) }%</Progress>
<React.Fragment>
```